# Converting zip file to memory stream throws Out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asynchronous

I'm creating an Azure function that will unzip a zip file full of .csv files, parse the contents, and save data to a database. I'm stuck on the very first step: unzip a zip file.

After reading lots of other threads (including [Azure downloadtostreamasync method hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526249/azure-downloadtostreamasync-method-hangs)) this is what I have:

```
 public async static Task<MemoryStream> GetMemoryStreamAsync(CloudFile inBoundfile)
 {
    MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
    await inBoundfile.DownloadToStreamAsync(memstream).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return memstream;
 }
```

The zip file I'm testing with is 515,069KB.  When that method is called, it seems to just hang, but eventually throws an Out of Memory exception. I've also tried doing it non-async (which throws the same error) and I've tried it w/o the `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, and in that case, it throws an error with something like `directory corrupt` (or somethin'.. I forget what exactly).

Oh, I also found a thread that said to put the Azure App at 64bit, which I did.

There MUST be a solution, but I'm not finding it!!

Comment: Use a "streaming" unzipper that doesn't require loading the entire shebang into memory at once.

Comment: Or use a `FileStream` instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey... ok... that sounds promising.  I also have to confess I have no idea how to do that. It's taken me all day to cobble this much together from piecing together all kinds of tidbits from lots of sources!  I wish I could find a tutorial on this!!

Comment: Will a FileStream work in an Azure Function App?

Comment: Good question.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715945.  Note that, if you're reading sequentially (which you should be), a FileStream and a MemoryStream should be morally equivalent, except that the FileStream won't chew up all of your memory.

Comment: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Comment: okay, so...  Given a CloudFile, how do I convert it to a FileStream and not a Memory Stream?  Creating a new filestream requires a path to a file... that's why i was wondering if it could be used with a file stored in Azure Stortage.  (I'm googling this now, but not finding much)

Comment: i'm looking at the DotNetZip giyhub you linked to... Not seeing anything there about Azure Storage. It looks like it's all meant for local file system stuff. Am I wrong?